# Online resources to aid in understanding SAS results

Tags: sas, references

Every time I look at SAS's result page I get lost among the numbers.
Is there any online material that can help with understanding SAS's result page?

Comment: using a procedure without reading the manual, and wondering why it doesn't make sense? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best place to look for understanding SAS procedures is the [online documentation at the SAS support page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/).

For the output of a particular procedure, there is a "Displayed Output" page within the "Details" section which describes most of the output.  For example, here's the ["Displayed Output" page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glm_sect043.htm) for `proc glm`.

You can also look through the examples the documentation provides in the "Examples" section.  Using `proc glm` again, here is a [list of examples](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glm_sect046.htm) in which the syntax and output are described pretty well.

Comment: @Joe, you may want to also check out CV's list of [SAS resources on meta](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/816/1036). Also to Mike, you might want to consider adding this to that same meta answer (thanks for the resource!)

Comment: @AndyW Thanks for the heads-up.  I forgot about that thread (even though it's in my favorites).  I added this resource to that answer.

Answer (score 1):

To gain some more context, also read a statistics text book that describes your analysis technique of choice. Try to link the theory you are reading to the output you see on the screen. Make this kind of link already helps you to understand what you are reading in the book. For example, for a simple linear regression common outputs are the significance of the coefficients and the R². Good luck!